# custom comparetor in stl

Tags: stl, priority-queue, comparator

This has been driving me nuts for 3 hours. Anybody see a reason why this isn't working?

```
struct sortByPropRev
{
    bool operator()(const cust_type &a, const cust_type &b) const
    {
        return a.prop > b.prop;
    }
};
...
priority_queue<cust_type, vector<cust_type>, sortByPropRev> x;
```

I get compile errors:
`Error C2664: 'bool (cust_type &,cust_type &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const cust_type' to 'cust_type &'`

and 2 more just like it but on different lines of `algorithm.h`

Comment: `struct cust_type {int a, int b, ...; cust_type(int a, int b, ...) : a(a), b(b) {} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the problem. I t was in a different part of the code that was calling the same algorithm functions. Sorry to bother everybody and thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You gave it b.pprop, vs a.prop. I think given the error that the compiler failed to parse the struct's definition properly- check for syntax errors in the code just above it.